# Position relative and height 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I have jQuery plugin [splitter](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.splitter) and it only work If I set the container to fixed height, if I set height to 100% it don't work. If I run the plugin without `height()` the height is 0.

Why the height is 0 with `position: relative` and `height: 100%`? Is it possible to make it work with 100% height, or do I always need to have fixed height?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7fMDz/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an element to have a percentage height not be 0, it has to have a parent with a height.  If you put a container around it with height: 200px or something, it will be 100% of the parent, so 200px;

```
<div style="height: 200px">  
  <div id="foo">...</div>
</div>
```

See fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/7fMDz/2/

Alternatively, you could do:

```
$('#foo').height($(window).height()).split();
```

If you are trying to get it to be 100% height of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

jcubic, try again with code below:

```
$(function() {
    $('#foo').height($( window ).height()).split({
        orientation:'vertical',
        limit:10
    });
});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7fMDz/5/

Comment: Yes, `$( window ).height()` will work but why it don't work with 100%, it's still fixed height.

Comment: jcubic, I understand. :)